# Unable to access MySQL from phpMyAdmin after setting root password in EasyPHP{WAMP}

Tags: php, mysql, wamp, easyphp, phpmyadmin

After successful setup on initial launch of MySQL, the page prompted me to set up ROOT password for security reasons.

On setting the password, am no longer able to access MySQL. The error is:

```
1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Looked up on the net and tried the following options in the `config.inc.php` from the phpmyadmin foler:

1. Set the authentication to "http" so that it prompts to enter the username and password

   ```
   /* Authentication type */
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'http';
   ```
2. Set up the correct password in the config file

   ```
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'myPwd';
   ```

None of them worked.

Can anyone suggest a workaround to access MySQL? Am not fussed about not being able to use the root account but would like to CRUD on the database using other username.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is my phpmyadmin config.inc.php file:

```
<?php

$i = 0;
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysql';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;

?>
```

That should be enough if Apache/PHP is running on the same machine as MySQL. Then you will  be prompted for a username and password. Enter root and the password that you set.

Comment: Thanks Sims! That worked. Had another problem due to using 'localhost' instead of '127.0.0.1'. Fixed using :

http://www.karinamyers.com/2009/08/howto-fix-phpmyadmin-displays-blank-page-after-logging-inhowto-fix-phpmyadmin-muestra-pagina-en-blanco-despues-de-logeo/

Appreciate the help.