# Does root IPv6 / ::1 address need password in phpMyAdmin?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, ipv6, easyphp

I'm new to setting up databases and I installed EasyPHP(e-devserver 14.1 VC9), managed to assign a password to root user's '127.0.0.1' address through phpMyAdmin because it said leaving the password blank was a bad idea. I edited 'localhost' to the same password. That gave me the 1045 error that so many other people got, managed to find the config file and edit it as [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540794/unable-to-access-mysql-from-myphpadmin-after-setting-root-password-in-easyphpwa?rq=1) said. However, IPv6 (the ::1 host) still has no password and while I could edit it in phpMyAdmin, if I get another error, I have found no documentation on where to edit that.

Would that address be vulnerable without a password, and if so how do I assign one without an error?

Comment: Changed the password with no issues, I seem to be able to access phpMyAdmin just fine still. Maybe I should make a new question for this, but if I'm going to make an admin account and have no desire to use the root accounts, what permissions should I grant them?

Comment: You usually want to leave 1 root account accessible for recovery and account management.  In a real environment, each subsequent account you create should only have limited permissions to access the databases they are meant to use (not be able to create databases, access other users' databases, or create users and grant privileges).  This is what the root account is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone had direct access to your server, they could attempt to connect to MySQL over IPv6 with the following command: `mysql -h ::1 -u root -p`

If there was a MySQL root user `'root'@'::1'` with no password, then they could get access.

Or if they were able to upload a PHP script to your server configured to connect over IPv6 using (PDO, mysqli etc) they could then get the script to connect.

You can check to see if root IPv6 connections are allowed by running the following query:

```
select user, host from mysql.user;
```

If you see anything in the list like `root     | ::1` or any other IPv6 address, there may be users configured with IPv6 host access.

To change the password of an existing IPv6 user, issue a query similar to:

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'::1' = PASSWORD('cleartext password');
```

If the user doesn't already exist and you want to add it, use:

```
CREATE USER 'root'@'::1' IDENTIFIED BY 'cleartext password';
```

You would then need to [grant](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/grant.html) the appropriate privileges to that account.